# How do I overlay Textures in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have an UV-mapped a mesh with a diffuse texture perfectly mapped, that appears in materials view.

Now, for ONLY specific parts of a texture, I want to *overlay* (as in screen, darken, multiply, soft light, *overlay*) another texture on top of a specific area of the diffuse texture. How is that typically done in blender? I don't want normal maps, I don't want specular, I just want diffuse and then alpha with overlay, likely using the mixRGB node.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Use the node tree you see here. The upper image node will point to that specific part of the image you want to overlay. You have to MASK those parts in the alpha channel  (I recommend you use .png with transparency) White=1 black=0 (non visible).

The second node it´s your regular image. The Texture coordinate nodes and mapping can share the plug for both images, but I´m doing it like this since I can sense in your post from what you write, this is what you want.

Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: Alright, so far so good. But, how do I control where the second texture shows up? If I change the UV map, it distorts the mapping of the original diffuse texture.

Comment: If you set up the graph I posted, you can control the position of the picture through the LOCATION of the mapping node (pos x,y,z)

Comment: I mean in terms of transparency. The location still maps the entire new texture over the entire original texture, but I only want part of the new texture mapped at all.

Comment: Factor from your image texture (alpha) is what trims (mask) your 2 textures. Use it.

Comment: Why do you run the color output through the Diffuse Shader Nodes before overlaying them? Wouldn't that work with the color input just as well?